# Как задать ход по 10 от 10 до 300 в паскале, чтобы запись проходила в 2 столбца?

Tags: pascal

Вот основа (писал сам) кода. Задача звучит так: вывести на экран в два стобца массовые концентрации серной кислоты в растворе при возрастании от 10г/л до 300г/л с шагом 10 г/л.

Вот, собственно, не получилось сделать, чтобы в 2 столбца шли и чтобы шло с шагом 10.

```
program p1;  
  uses crt;  
var min,max,a,z:real;  
begin  
     write('Vvesti minimum i max rkoncentracii: ');  
     min:=10 ;  
     max:=300 ;  
            while max>min do  
                  begin  
                  a:=min+10;  
                  z:=a+10;      if z>300 then break;  
                  writeln(z);  
                  end;  
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program p1;

uses crt;

var min, max, count:integer;

begin  
     writeln('Vvesti minimum i max rkoncentracii: ');  
     min:=10;  
     max:=300;

     count := min; 
     while count<=max do  
     begin  
         count := count+10;
         write(count:5);

         if count mod 20 <> 0 then writeln();  
     end;  
end.
```

Comment: огромноейшее тебе спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var
  min, max, step, n, curpos, endpos: Integer;
begin
  min:=10;
  max:=300;
  step:=10;
  n:=min;
  endpos:=(max-min) div step;
  if odd(endpos) Then inc(endpos);
  endpos:=endpos shr 1;
  for curpos:=1 to endpos do begin
    //Вместо строки вывод паскалевский, не помню уже как там было) 
    Memo1.Lines.Append(Format('%2d. %4d %10d. %4d', [curpos, n, curpos+endpos, n+(endpos*step)]));
    //Вроде так WriteLn(curpos:2, n:4, (curpos+endpos):10, (n+(endpos*step)):4);
    n:=n+step;
  end;
end.
```